# How can I specify the type of the field that an Annotation should be applied to in Java?

Tags: java, android, reflection, annotations

I'm creating a simple annotation, to help me inflating settings inside my Android application. The annotation is this:

```
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface CoreSettings {
    String name() default "";
}
```

I want to ensure it will only be used in fields which type extends a custom class named **BaseSettings**. In the example below, MainSettings extends the abstract class BaseSettings.

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {

    @CoreSettings("prefs")
    MainSettings settings;


    (...)

}
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can cause the compiler to issue an error message if you write the annotation on a field of the wrong type.

You cannot do this using just the `@Target` meta-annotation.  In addition, you need to write an annotation processor.  The annotation processor will examine each occurrence of the annotation `@CoreSettings` in your source code, and it issues an error (just like any other compiler error) if `@CoreSettings` is applied to a type that does not extend `BaseSettings`.  This is a short, simple annotation processor to write.

You will only get the compile-time warning when running the annotation processor, but you can add the `-processor ...` command-line argument to javac in your project's buildfile.

Comment: Great explanation, do you have any set of references or links for this case to share?

Comment: The [Checker Framework](http://CheckerFramework.org/) does this; for instance its [Nullness Checker](http://types.cs.washington.edu/checker-framework/current/checker-framework-manual.html#nullness-checker) permits you to write `@NonNull` or `@Nullable` on a field of reference type but not a field of primitive type such as `int`.  Other of the Checker Framework's type systems have similar restrictions.